# What's the smallest difference of any (2) numbers that can be formed by using each digit once 0-9?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Suppose you have **digits** = `{0,..,9}`.

Suppose you have an **input** which is a subset of **digits** with cardinality of at least `2`.

Consider all possible base 10 integers pairs **a** and **b** such that each element in **input** is used once in either **a** or **b** and with no leading `0`'s (an actual value of `0` is okay, though).

The `Solve` algorithm is find the minimum of the absolute value of the difference of all valid pairs from the input.

For example, if **input** = `{ 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7 }`.

There are lots of possible pairs that use each digit exactly once, for example **a** = `210` and **b** = `764` and **a** = `204` and **b** = `176`.

As it turns out the second pair has the minimum absolute value difference (`28`).

**input** will be provided to a `static` method called `Solve` as a string with each digit separated by a single space in ascending order.  You can assume that the input is valid and sorted.

**Question: What correct C# implementation of `Solve` has the best runtime (without just pre-computing/hardcoding each of the `~2^10` solutions individually)?**

Here's what I've tried so far and it seemed to work with the sample input (I did what was most intuitive and readable. I also broke it up into several methods with the hope each could be "unit" tested relatively easily to troubleshoot in case it didn't just "work" the first time.):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "0 1 2 4 6 7";
        var result = Solve(input);
    }

    private static int Solve(string input)
    {
        var digits = input.Split(' ').Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToArray();
        return GetSmallestDifference(digits) ?? -1;
    }

    public static int? GetSmallestDifference(IEnumerable<int> input)
    {
        var validInput = ValidateInput(input);

        var candidates = GenerateCandidates(validInput);

        int? best = null;
        foreach (var candidate in candidates)
        {
            var current = Math.Abs(candidate.Item1 - candidate.Item2);
            if (current < (best ?? int.MaxValue))
            {
                best = current;
            }
        }
        return best;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> GenerateCandidates(int[] validInput)
    {
        var found = new HashSet<string>();

        var nonZeroDigits = validInput.Except(new[] { 0 });
        var max = int.Parse(string.Join("", nonZeroDigits.OrderByDescending(i => i)));
        for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
        {
            var potential = i;
            var complements = GetComplements(potential, validInput);
            if (complements != null)
            {
                foreach (var complement in complements)
                {
                    var signature = GetSignature(potential, complement);
                    if (!found.Contains(signature))
                    {
                        found.Add(signature);

                        yield return Tuple.Create(potential, complement);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static string GetSignature(int potential, int complement)
    {
        // Sort it so we don't get duplicates.
        var key = new[] { potential, complement }.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
        var formatted = string.Format("{0} {1}", key[0], key[1]);
        return formatted;
    }

    private static List<int> GetComplements(int potential, int[] validInput)
    {
        var remaining = validInput.ToList();
        var digits = potential.ToString().Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())).ToArray();

        foreach (var d in digits)
        {
            // This means the potential isn't a valid candidate.
            if (!remaining.Contains(d))
            {
                return null;
            }

            remaining.Remove(d);
        }

        // This means there were no other digits to choose.
        if (remaining.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            var complements = new List<int>();
            Scramble(complements, "", remaining);
            return complements;
        }
    }

    private static void Scramble(List<int> complements, string result, IEnumerable<int> remaining)
    {
        if (remaining.Any())
        {
            foreach (var i in remaining)
            {
                var childResult = result + i;
                var childRemaining = remaining.Except(new[] { i });

                Scramble(complements, childResult, childRemaining);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!result.StartsWith("0") || result.Length == 1)
            {
                var intResult = int.Parse(result);
                complements.Add(intResult);
            }
        }
    }

    private static int[] ValidateInput(IEnumerable<int> input)
    {
        // Make sure (2) integers were entered.
        if (input == null || input.Count() < 2)
        {
            // TODO
            throw new Exception();
        }

        // Make sure you don't have duplicates.
        var result = input.Distinct().ToArray();

        // Make sure the numbers are in range.
        if (result.Min() < 0 || result.Max() > 9)
        {
            // TODO
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

*(This question was recently asked by another user but appears to have been deleted by the user; I already came up with an answer, though, so I didn't want SO to lose it.  I re-worded and re-formatted the question, slightly.)*

Comment: Can't quite put my finger on it, but I think there is a possible algorithm with linear complexity. Divide the set of digits in two (so here, two numbers of three digits). Pick the first digit to minimize the difference (so here it'd have to be either 0-1, 1-2, or 6-7). Then pick the remaining digits to maximize the lowest number and minimize the highest one (which leads to 642 and 701). What I'm missing, for a complete algorithm, is finding out "why picking 1-2 as first digits works better than 0-1 or 6-7"

Comment: @KooKiz That's a good point.  Considering only candidate pairs whose count of digits' difference is at most 1 is one optimization to make (`0` if **input** has an even number of digits).

Comment: Well once you've fixed the first two digits you've already picked the bigger and smaller number.  Now for the remaining digits you want the bigger number to be smallest (`0` and `1`) and the smaller number to be biggest (`4` and `2`).

Comment: So take the remaining digits and sort and partition them.  The smaller digits will go on the larger number (sorted descending) and larger digits will go on the smaller number (sorted ascending).  Hmm maybe that's the trick @KooKiz?  And then you'd just need to think about the case of having an odd number of digits.

Comment: To be fair I didn't try to approach this from the math/analysis side, first, because I wanted to show the OP brute force - usually that's a first conceptual step - can you do it naively - before doing it "sneakily" (sometimes understanding and stepping through the brute force approach will bring to light how to be sneaky).

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there was corner cases making the problem slightly more complicated (I'd have to write the full algorithm and try various inputs to make sure), but yeah at that point it's almost certain there is a solution with linear complexity

Comment: @KooKiz Sometimes I can't read.  Since you don't which of the choices to pick, maybe try each minimized pair, since there will only be a few to check?

Comment: Would probably be a better fit at [codegolf.SE] as it's a programming challenge.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer has yet to be shown to be optimal, so I'm not accepting it - feel free to improve it or post a better one!**

I took the idea from *KooKiz* in the comments of this question and implemented it.  Even for the largest possible complex input (when **input** == **digits**, which happens to have even cardinality, the more complex case) it seemed to run `<100ms` on my machine each time compared to whatever it was before (I didn't even try to let it finish running for larger inputs).

```
class SneakierProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "0 1 2 4 6 7";
        var result = Solve(input);
    }

    private static int Solve(string input)
    {
        int? best = null;
        int a, b;

        var unvalidatedDigits = input.Split(' ').Select(i => int.Parse(i));

        var digits = ValidateInput(unvalidatedDigits);

        // Special case because the even algorithm doesn't play nicely if there are exactly (2)
        // digits and one of them is 0.
        if (digits.Length == 2)
        {
            // However since it's already sorted and there are only 2 digits we know what to do.
            best = digits[1] - digits[0];
        }
        else if (digits.Length % 2 == 1)
        {
            // Are there an odd number of digits to choose from?
            // If so the most sigificant needs to be 0 for the smaller number.
            var b0 = 0;

            // That forces the most sigificant needs to be the minimum non-0 for the larger number.
            var a0 = digits.Except(new[] { 0 }).Min();

            // The 0 for b0 doesn't count/shouldn't be excluded.
            // Note remaining now has an even number of digits left.
            var remaining = digits.Except(new[] { a0 });
            OptimizeRemainingDigits(remaining, a0, b0, out a, out b);

            best = a - b;
        }
        else
        {
            // There are an even number of digits to choose from, so each number will contain
            // an equal number of digits.  The most sigificant digits most affect the difference
            // so minimizing them is our greatest concern.  Since the array is sorted we only
            // need to consider adjacent pairs.

            var nonZeroDigits = digits.Except(new[] { 0 }).ToArray();

            // There will be one less adjacent pair than the total to choose from.
            var adjacentPairIndices = Enumerable.Range(0, nonZeroDigits.Length - 1);

            // Project the adjacent pairs.
            var adjacentPairs = adjacentPairIndices.Select(i => new
            {
                // The larger will be one past the index.
                Larger = nonZeroDigits[i + 1],
                // The smaller will be at the index.
                Smaller = nonZeroDigits[i]
            });

            // Group adjacent pairs by their difference.
            var groupedAdjacentPairs = adjacentPairs.ToLookup(pair => pair.Larger - pair.Smaller);

            // Find the minimum difference.
            var minimumDifference = groupedAdjacentPairs.Select(g => g.Key).Min();

            // Consider only the adjacent pairs that have minimum difference.
            var candidates = groupedAdjacentPairs[minimumDifference];
            foreach (var candidate in candidates)
            {
                // The most sigificant needs to be smaller for the smaller number.
                var b0 = candidate.Smaller;

                // The most sigificant needs to be larger for the larger number.
                var a0 = candidate.Larger;

                // Both used digits need to be excluded.
                // Note remaining still has an even number of digits left.
                var remaining = digits.Except(new[] { a0, b0 });
                OptimizeRemainingDigits(remaining, a0, b0, out a, out b);

                var possibleBetter = a - b;
                if (possibleBetter < (best ?? int.MaxValue))
                {
                    best = possibleBetter;
                }
            }

        }

        return best ?? -1;
    }

    private static void OptimizeRemainingDigits(
        IEnumerable<int> remaining, 
        int a0, 
        int b0, 
        out int a, 
        out int b)
    {
        // Acculmuate the digits of a on a string.
        var aString = a0.ToString();

        // Acculumate the digits of b on a string (b can be 0, in which case don't count that as a digit).
        var bString = b0 == 0 ? "" : b0.ToString();

        // Each number will get half the remaining digits.
        var digitsPerNumber = remaining.Count() / 2;

        // The larger number gets the smaller digits from least to greatest 
        // to minimize its overall value.
        aString += string.Join("", remaining.
            OrderBy(i => i).Take(digitsPerNumber));

        // The smaller number gets the larger digits from greatest to least 
        // to maximize its overall value.
        bString += string.Join("", remaining.
            OrderByDescending(i => i).Take(digitsPerNumber));

        a = int.Parse(aString);
        b = int.Parse(bString);
    }

    private static int[] ValidateInput(IEnumerable<int> input)
    {
        // Make sure at least (2) integers were entered.
        if (input == null || input.Count() < 2)
        {
            // TODO
            throw new Exception();
        }

        // Make sure you don't have duplicates.
        var result = input.Distinct().ToArray();

        // Make sure the numbers are in range.
        if (result.Min() < 0 || result.Max() > 9)
        {
            // TODO
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you ever come across this answer, OP from this deleted question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522598/smallest-difference-from-a-number-of-distinct-decimal-digits-c-sharp#36522598 - the implementation of the problem became much easier (to write and quicker to run) when math was applied to analyze the properties of the question.  It could easily be the case that whatever contest this was from has other problems that have "tricks" to it - you might do well focusing more on doing puzzle-sized proofs more than coding.  You should be able to find them all over StackExchange and Google.

Comment: What does your program output for `{6,7,8,9}`? Also, could you outline the algorithm in words?

Comment: When `"6 7 8 9"` is the input string it considers (3) possible pairs of digits for the most significant digit `({6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 9})`.  It then optimizes the remaining digits to get `({69, 78}, {79, 86}, {87, 96})` and computes differences `(9, 7, 9)`, choosing `7` corresponding to `{79, 86}` as its final choice.  In a nutshell it tries to figure out the most significant digits first, if it can't it brute forces through a few possibilities, optimizing the other digits...

Answer (score 0):

Sort your input: e.g {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7}
Then we need to make a low number, and a high number, our goal to is maximize the low number, and minimize the hi number
Hi-low number can be separated when you pick the first digits:

- hi: 2--
- lo: 1--

Take turn choosing digit for hi & lo (thats left in the pool), choose that largest possible digit for low, and the smallest possible digit for hi

```
[17_][23_] -> [176][234]
```

**Strategy for choosing the first digits**

> For input with zero, since you cant choose zero as your first digits,
>   you temporary remove the zero from your digit pool before choosing
>   first digits, and re-add it later in the correct oder to your sorted
>   pool

...

> For **odd-count** input (you determine this **BEFORE** removing zero if happens)
>   Choose the smallest digit for `hi`, and largest digit for `lo`, because that minimize the difference (`lo` first digit is understand as 0):

```
Sample on {0,1,2,4,6} -> remove zero {1,2,4,6} -> choose 1 & 6  
[1__]  
[_6_]  
-> readd zero {0,2,4}
-> take turn add to hi, lo
-> [102][_64]
```

...

> For **even-count** input, the strategy to pick the first digits is not as
>   straight forward as in the odd-case. In this case you have to **pick a
>   pair of consecutive number in a sorted collection so that their GAP is smallest**,
>   GAP is defined as follow:
>
> Given **pair(a,b)** where **a < b**
>   if **(a,b)** is a *level-1 pair*
>   ======> GAP(a,b) = b - a
>   else
>   ======> GAP(a,b) = (10-b) + a
>
> a *level-1* pair is pair such that you will use its content to choose first digits in hi & lo

**Example run with {6, 7, 8, 9}**

```
level-1   | [6,7]:1 | [7,8]:1  | [8,9]:1  | same gap, cant decide best pair
sub-level | {8,9}:9 | {6,9}:7* | {6,7}:9  | pair[1] have smallest gap, trace back level-1
We now use [7,8] for our lo & hi first digits
hi[8_]    >run normal strategy>     hi[86]
lo[7_]                              lo[79]
```

> for each level-1 pair you know that our strategy to pick the remaining
>   digit is choosing largest-smallest consecutive digit in our digit
>   pool, take advantage of this, we can compute low level gap of each
>   pair according to given formula

**Implementation**

```
    void Solve()
    {
        int[] inputs = { 6, 7, 8, 9 }; //Make sure its sorted
        LinkedList<int> digitPool = new LinkedList<int>(inputs);
        Queue<int> hi = new Queue<int>();
        Queue<int> lo = new Queue<int>();

        ChooseFirstDigit(hi, lo, digitPool);

        bool flag = true;
        while (digitPool.Count != 0)
        {
            if (flag)
            {
                hi.Enqueue(digitPool.First());
                digitPool.RemoveFirst();
                flag = !flag;
            }
            else
            {
                lo.Enqueue(digitPool.Last());
                digitPool.RemoveLast();
                flag = !flag;
            }
        }

        while (hi.Count != 0)
            Console.Write(hi.Dequeue());
        Console.WriteLine("");
        while (lo.Count != 0)
            Console.Write(lo.Dequeue());
    }

    void ChooseFirstDigit(Queue<int> hi, Queue<int> lo, LinkedList<int> digitPool)
    {
        bool hasZero = false;
        bool oddCount = (digitPool.Count % 2 != 0);

        // { 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8}
        if (digitPool.First() == 0)
        {
            hasZero = true;
            digitPool.RemoveFirst(); // {1, 2, 4, 6, 7}
        }

        if (oddCount)
        {
            hi.Enqueue(digitPool.First());              
            lo.Enqueue(digitPool.Last());
            digitPool.RemoveFirst();
            digitPool.RemoveLast();
        }
        else
        {
            var bestPair = digitPool.First;
            List<int> minGap = calculateGap(bestPair, hasZero);

            var pair = bestPair.Next; //pair[0,1]
            while (pair != digitPool.Last)
            {
                List<int> gap = calculateGap(pair, hasZero);
                for (int i = 0; i < gap.Count; ++i)
                {
                    if (gap[i] < minGap[i])
                    {
                        //found a better pair
                        minGap = gap;
                        bestPair = pair;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (minGap[i] < gap[i])
                        break;
                }

                pair = pair.Next;               
            }

            lo.Enqueue(bestPair.Value);
            hi.Enqueue(bestPair.Next.Value);
            digitPool.Remove(bestPair.Next);
            digitPool.Remove(bestPair);
        }       

        if (hasZero) digitPool.AddFirst(0);
    }

    List<int> calculateGap(LinkedListNode<int> bestPair, bool hasZero)
    {
        LinkedList<int> clonedPool = new LinkedList<int>(bestPair.List);
        clonedPool.Remove(bestPair.Value);
        clonedPool.Remove(bestPair.Next.Value);

        List<int> gap = new List<int>();
        gap.Add(bestPair.Next.Value - bestPair.Value); //Level-1 GAP


        if (hasZero) clonedPool.AddFirst(0);

        while (clonedPool.Count != 0) //Sub-level GAPs
        {
            gap.Add((10 - clonedPool.Last()) + clonedPool.First());
            clonedPool.RemoveFirst();
            clonedPool.RemoveLast();
        }

        return gap;
    }
```

Comment: How about {6,7,8,9} ?

Comment: it output 78 and 69, thats correct i think

Comment: `78 - 69 = 9`, but `86 - 79 = 7` is smaller

Comment: Oops, hmm, i think there more to when you pick the first digits for hi and lo, need to reconsider this

Comment: @גלעד ברקן I updated the solution, thank you for pointed that error out

Answer (score 0):

Order and group choices by ascending negative difference:

```
{0,1,2,4,6,7}

{[0-7],[0-6,1-7],[1-6,2-7],[0-4,2-6]
,[1-4,4-7],[0-2,2-4,4-6],[0-1,1-2,6-7]}
```

Assuming even input, the left-most digit will be chosen from the last group; the rest, from first to last:

```
While groups are not emptied, holding candidates for each spot 
from left to right, choose the right-most digit you can and proceed left:

There are two choices for the left-most digit but only one for the second 
digit, which dictates 2-1,0-7 and the only remaining digits, 4-6
```

Another example:

```
{6,7,8,9}

{[6-9],[6-8,7-9],[6-7,7-8,8-9]}

Again, only one choice for the second digit, which dictates 8-7,6-9
```